# How to display "number of items" in a tableview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uikit

What's the best way to implement showing a number in a small circle on a UITableView row, much like is seen on the 'Inbox' row in the image below?

[alt text http://www.madebyfiga.com/images/misc/iPhoneNumberInCircle.jpg](http://www.madebyfiga.com/images/misc/iPhoneNumberInCircle.jpg)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a button in a `UITableViewCell`, style it and change it's text for every row inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. You can also hide it for rows where you don't want it.

Comment: Are there no convenient methods to do this? Seems odd that Apple left it out of UIKit given it is so common amongst so many apps?

Comment: This is a convienient method. I don't think even almighty Apple can think of every possible things developers could want with `UITableViewCell` out-of-the-box so they provided developers with the possibility of easily adjusting them to their needs.